# Creating building's shadow over buildings in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, visualisation

I want to create a map with the shadows projected from the building.

There are a few methods to create this, but all of them are not so accurate. The Translate Method has the problem that is not continous from the build. And the 2.5D Method is a quite good when I set this as a backward layer. But the problem is the shadow of a big tower is not over the small buildings, as well as the water tank box over the building not project the shadow.

I think this is a typical real 3D issue. But in QGIS is possible to solve this?

[image]

This image illustrates the question. The shadows should consider if the shape next is lower or higher.